# Passing back data with increasing row indices using Sparse Command

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

By default the sparse command passes back the non-zero elements in a matrix arranged by increasing column indices:

```
A = [ 0 0 1; 0 0 2; 0 2 1];

B = sparse(A)
B =

   (3,2)        2
   (1,3)        1
   (2,3)        2
   (3,3)        1
```

Is there a way to change this so that it passes back the sparse matrix in increasing row indices? In this case

```
    B =
       (1,3)        1
       (2,3)        2
       (3,2)        2
       (3,3)        1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the *displayed* values to have increasing row indices, there is a way, although it's a little hackish:

1. Capture the output of `sparse` using [`evalc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalc.html).
2. That gives a string with lines separatesd by newline characters. Split it into different rows and concatenate them horizontally (padding with spaces) using [`char`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html). This gives a 2D char array.
3. Sort the rows of that array except for the first (if using [`format`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) `compact`) or first three (if using `format loose`) with [`sortrows`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html). This makes smaller row indices appear first. You may want to remove the first row or the first three rows (which contain `ans =` and blank lines).
4. Display that using [`disp`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/disp.html).

Example using `format compact`:

```
format compact
A = [ 0 0 1; 0 0 2; 0 2 1];         %// data
s = evalc('sparse(A)');             %// step 1
s = char(strsplit(s,'\n'));         %// step 2
s(2:end,:) = sortrows(s(2:end,:));  %// step 3, asuming format compact
disp(s)                             %// step 4
```

This gives

```
ans =            

   (1,3)        1
   (2,3)        2
   (3,2)        2
   (3,3)        1
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.

The reason is because MATLAB stores everything as 1D vectors inside, independently of the dimensions of the matrix. This means that the actually index of the values you see there are `[6 7 8 9]` , but MATLAB changes them to matrix indices (using `ind2sub`).

Also, in sparse matrices just that index and the value are stored. So while in matrix `A` everything is stored, B looks like

```
ind=[6 7 8 9]
val=[2 1 2 1]
```

in memory.

The only thing you can do about this is actually permuting/transposing the matrix, but then you'll loose the indexing. However, I am unsure of what do you want his for, as MATLAB only understand this way of ordering the data. If you want it for plotting, then you can just reorder them.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I need them ordered this way so that I can pass a sparse Hessain matrix to IPOPT. It is complaining when I do not arrange in order of increasing row indices: Hessian must be an n x n sparse, symmetric and lower triangular matrix with row indices in increasing order, where n is the number of variables.

Comment: @user3784721 do you also need those indexes? You could just transpose the matrix. Else, reorder them yourself!